# How to replace a line within a text file regardless to its current value?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to replace a line inside the Preferences file of Google Chrome in order to change current homepage.

In my computer, i've http://www.google.com which is defined as a default homepage, and therefor i need to replace (inside the Preferences file) the following line :

```
         "homepage": "http://www.google.com/",
```

Replace with :

```
         "homepage": "http://www.MyWebsite.com/",
```

So in order to do this, i am using a code which look something like this :

```
          string PreferencesFile = File.ReadAllText(file);
          PreferencesFile.Replace(FirstLine,SecondLine);
          File.WriteAllText(file,PreferencesFile);
```

But the problem is that in each computer, there  is a different homepage.

How to replace the line below

```
         "homepage": "http://www.what-ever-site-is-here.com/",
```

With

```
         "homepage": "http://www.MyWebsite.com/",
```

And which values should be affected to FirstLine and SecondLine variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should read all the *lines*, replace any line starting with `"homepage":` and then rewrite. For example:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (lines[i].StartsWith("\"homepage\": "))
    {
        lines[i] = "\"homepage\": \"http://www.MyWebsite.com\"",";
    }
}
File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
```

Comment: What about if there was some spaces before the line we want to replace ?

Comment: How to use the * Operator to match all possible occurancies before that line.. ?

Comment: @ShikataGaNai: It's not clear what you mean - particularly your comment about the * operator, which has no meaning for strings. It sounds like you might just want to change `StartsWith` to `Contains`, but it's not really clear...

Comment: exactly what i was searching for. Thankyou!